# Identity and possible generalization of the reflective periodic continued fractions

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

This is just for curiosity. I noticed, that certain multiples of square rooted numbers can be formed with a periodic continued fraction. Addition to that periodicity is reflective by nature. Say for example:

$$9 \sqrt3 = [15; 1, 1, 2, 3, 15, 3, 2, 1, 1, 30]$$

Where:

- start element of the continued fraction: $15$
- repetitive period is: $1, 1, 2, 3, 15, 3, 2, 1, 1, 30$
- middle element is: $15$
- reflective parts are: $1, 1, 2, 3$ and $3, 2, 1, 1$
- the last element of the period is the double of the start element: $30$

Other example:

$$16 \sqrt2 = [22; 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 11, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 44]$$

It looks like this sort of sequences occur with (square?) rooted (prime?) numbers multiplied with powered? (prime?) numbers.

I want to know, if this behavior is identified somehow and if following the above five step procedure can produce a fixed set of (irrational?) numbers.

The most curious I'm about the consequence of the reflection of the number sequence. Is there an explanation for it?

Comment: Note $9\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{3^5}$ and $16\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{2^9}$. Perhaps they are square roots of prime powers (odd powers, that is)?

Comment: all true, Some part of the reflection fact was proved by Galois. I will see what links I can find.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_continued_fraction#Reduced_surds

Comment: That was a nice tragedic piece of history behind Galois!