# How do you proof that the simply periodic continuous fraction is palindromic for the square root of positive primes?

Tags: number-theory, roots, continued-fractions, palindrome

I have formulated this question based on the initial curiosity and further investigation of the topic posted here: [Identity and possible generalization of the reflective periodic continued fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280839/identity-and-possible-generalization-of-the-reflective-periodic-continued-fracti)

How do you proof that for the square root of any positive prime, the [simply periodic](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5e2a/962830baa83e5c1b02f6357cea21860bde35.pdf?_ga=2.173551584.272489781.1495281684-1150058576.1495281684) continuous fraction is **palindromic**?

It should be true both for even:

$$\sqrt{Z^+_{prime}} = [a_0; a_1, a_2, ..., a_2, a_1, 2a_0]$$

and for odd:

$$\sqrt{Z^+_{prime}} = [a_0; a_1, ..., a_n, ..., a_1, 2a_0]$$

sequences.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#As_periodic_continued_fractions

Comment: It's no easier to prove it for primes than to prove it for positive nonsquare integers generally, but it is a bit long. Better to get yourself a good intro Number Theory text, many of them include the proof.

Comment: I found many papers talking about the symmetry of the conjugate of the quadratic surd. But I didn't find any of them dealing with palindromic part exactly. I'd appreciate any reference that deals with the exact palindromic case I'm pointing. Of cource handling primes is not required, I thought it could narrow the problem but maybe it doesn't but rather complicates the proof...

Comment: Have you tracked down any of the references in my answer?

Comment: Yes. I found Roberts and Stark and got some ideas. Still trying to find other three sources if they are available online. I'll be back after doing some work with given exercises.

Comment: Also Rosen, "Elementary Number Theory" (10.4, pages 387-388) was online. So far it has the exact point made toward palindromic part and double ending of the sequence. It just needs to be modified a bit to fit to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are five textbooks that deal with the palindromic feature of the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt n$. Some give detailed proofs, some give it as an exercise with strong hints. All require reading some of the material leading up to the problem. There's just no really easy way – you have to roll your sleeves up and get to work!

1. Rosen, [Elementary Number Theory](http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~lavric/Rosen%20-%20Elementary%20number%20theory%20and%20its%20applications.pdf), 4th edition, Section 12.4.
2. Roberts, [Elementary Number Theory](https://archive.org/download/ElementaryNumberTheory_841/Roberts-ElementaryNumberTheory.pdf), Chapter XIII, problem 17, part vi (book includes complete solutions to all problems).
3. Shanks, [Solved and Unsolved Problems in Number Theory](http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/Number%20Theory%20Daniel%20Shanks.pdf), Exercise 138, page 186.
4. Steuding, [Diophantine Analysis](https://books.google.fi/books?id=af3LBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Section 5.4.
5. Stark, [An Introduction to Number Theory](https://www.scribd.com/doc/129486179/Harold-M-Stark-an-Introduction-to-Number-Theory-Bookos-org), Chapter 7, Miscellaneous Exercise 18.

Comment: @hard, all those links were edited in by user MarkokraM. They may all be violations of copyright (I am not a lawyer). The Rosen link is probably to the first edition of the textbook. If the material on the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt n$ is there, it will be in Section 10.4. The link to the Roberts book seems to be broken. Ditto for the link to the Shanks book, and also the link to the Stark book.

Comment: Right, I looked in that Section 10.4 and found nothing about palindromes among the partial quotients.  Anyway, broken links is a hobby for me, so I'll see if I can locate legitimate online replacements.